How do i make 3 column to arrange in 1?
I have 3 column, i need to make one column,

Check image i have set manual for first 2 row to 1 column. What I want is get one list for 3 column.I have tried Transpose but it just transfer column to row line.
Transpose works for one row to one column i have to make manually for each row. but need it for whole.
How do i make 3 column to arrange in 1?

Using TOCOL to arrange 3 columns into one
You can use the TOCOL function to accomplish this.
Formula
=TOCOL(A1:C)

Sample Output



1.0827
1.08208
1.08266

Output




1.0831
1.08242
1.08244

1.0827


1.08256
1.08219
1.0824

1.08208






1.08266






1.0831






1.08242






1.08244






1.08256






1.08219






1.0824



References:
TOCOL function

dont know why i got minus voting but i got what i needed, thank you.
